# How can there be a finite number of Logical Reads if the SQL Server machine is rebooted?

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following query on AdventureWorks2014 database first time after rebooting the SQL Server machine.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT c.CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
JOIN Sales.Customer c ON oh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

As I understand that a logical read would mean a 'Cache Hit', which means data is read from the SQL Server cache instead of disk.

> Table 'SalesOrderDetail'. Scan count 1, logical reads 276, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 274, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

How is it possible that if a machine is rebooted, any entry is contained in SQL Server cache keeping in mind there are more than 1 database on that server and hence we see a logical read of 276 ?

Answer (score 2):

[Reading Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/reading-pages?view=sql-server-2017):

> The I/O from an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine includes logical and physical reads. **A logical read occurs every time the Database Engine requests a page from the buffer cache. If the page is not currently in the buffer cache, a physical read first copies the page from disk into the cache.**
>
> **Read-Ahead**
>
> **The Database Engine supports a performance optimization mechanism called read-ahead. Read-ahead anticipates the data and index pages needed to fulfill a query execution plan and brings the pages into the buffer cache before they are actually used by the query.** This allows computation and I/O to overlap, taking full advantage of both the CPU and the disk.

And your example:

logical reads **276**, physical reads 1, **read-ahead reads 274**

Answer (score 1):

A logical read is a read of a data page from cache, regardless of whether it was already in cache or not. Queries always read data from memory, never directly on disk.

In this case, it looks like data were read from disk using read-ahead reads. But even if read-ahead wasn't employed, you would still have the same logical reads because it doesn't matter if pages were brought into cache using single page IO, full extent reads, or multi-extent read-ahead reads.